# When i open heroku i have a problem with strapi with h10 code

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

i have this problem when i open heroku and run heroku logs --tail
The app crashed and dont see my app strapi in heroku.................

```html
2020-05-04T19:05:38.602418+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=strapi-inmobiliaria-gatsby.herokuapp.com request_id=2b5c1e98-7aaf-4362-905f-bf0e17391fe0 fwd="190.244.81.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-04T19:05:38.862307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strapi-inmobiliaria-gatsby.herokuapp.com request_id=629c8bb2-8e68-4b8d-8d35-919c95130eb2 fwd="190.244.81.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-04T19:13:18.189908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=strapi-inmobiliaria-gatsby.herokuapp.com request_id=cd2366d2-1851-4ed2-bf70-72d8db61c1c4 fwd="190.244.81.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-04T19:13:18.538292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strapi-inmobiliaria-gatsby.herokuapp.com request_id=c757b34d-7944-4a5b-944b-ae0dcb84affc fwd="190.244.81.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I search the problem but i no sure what it is.

Its my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "bienesraices",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "knex": "<0.20.0",
    "mysql": "latest",
    "pg": "^8.0.3",
    "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-admin": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-plugin-graphql": "^3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.0.0-beta.20.1",
    "strapi-utils": "3.0.0-beta.20.1"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "13a8b7a9-81dc-4560-98f1-0ec0ec1769c0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

```html
Running printenv on ⬢ strapi-inmobiliaria-gatsby... up, run.3613 (Free)
NODE_HOME=/app/.heroku/node
NODE_ENV=production
WEB_MEMORY=512
DYNO=run.3613
PWD=/app
LINES=30
HOME=/app
DATABASE_PORT=5432
NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
DATABASE_URL=postgres://cbf************:d0******************************@ec2-52******40.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3******ntmu
PORT=42473
MEMORY_AVAILABLE=512
DATABASE_NAME=d3************mu
COLUMNS=120
DATABASE_USERNAME=cbf******
WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
SHLVL=1
PATH=/app/.heroku/node/bin:/app/.heroku/yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin
```

### And my procfile i dont know it´s ok

web: node config/environments/production/server.json

Comment: Can you share your `heroku run printenv`  and your `Procfile` ?

Comment: Yes i edit the post and share printenv and procfile

Comment: I strongly recommend you to delete the postgres database(if its empty or dummy one) in heroku. If not at-least change the password. Looks like you have pasted all the valid credentials here..

Comment: Your `Procfile` should be like `web: node strapi start`

Answer (score 1):

I just added self assigned SSL object from [strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#database) and it works. Add the rows into `database.js` file by follow below steps.

```
ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL_SELF', false), // For self-signed certificates
    },
    options: {
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
    }, `
```

Complete `database.js` file looks like

```
module.exports = ({
        env
    }) => ({
        defaultConnection: 'default',
        connections: {
            default: {
                connector: 'bookshelf',
                settings: {
                    client: 'postgres',
                    host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 5432),
                    database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'strapi'),
                    username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', ''),
                    password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
                    //add this line
                    ssl: {
                        rejectUnauthorized: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL_SELF', false), // For self-signed certificates
                    },
                },
                // add this line
                options: {
                    ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

And my `server.js` file looks like

```
module.exports = ({
    env
}) => ({
    host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
    port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
    admin: {
        auth: {
            secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-beta.19-to-beta.19.4.html#listened-host-changed

Because Heroku is expecting Strapi to be running on a publicly accessible port you need to set the `host` variable in `config/environments/*/server.json` to use `0.0.0.0` instead of localhost.

(The Strapi Heroku guide is not up to date yet)

Comment: This is my server.json in production. I make follow the instructions and the server.json its same, i delete cache and make build and git push heroku master but i have the same error.
{
  "host": "${process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0'}",
  "port": "${process.env.PORT || 1337}",
  "production": true,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

added this too and it's working now..

```
 ssl: {
     rejectUnauthorized: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL_SELF', false), // For self-signed certificates
            },
          },
          options: {
            ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
          },
```